# Show all instances of custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a custom object called Projects. How do I create a VF page that shows all of the instances of that object?

Do I need a custom apex controller querying the database and if so what would that look like?

Comment: How many records do you have? There are limits to how many records can be returned.

Comment: Agree with @Mike Chale.  Also, is there a reason a list view would not suffice?  Do you have a tab for this object?

Comment: only have 8 instances. I want a tab in Salesforce1 that shows all the instances

Answer (score 6):

You should have a look at [StandardSetController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) and any Visualforce examples that contain the `recordSetVar` in them.

Check http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_list_views.htm for example.

By default you can achieve a list with 20 records and previous/next controls that will let you paginate through it. Anything more like more rows per page - you'd need an Apex controller extension or completely custom controller. Similar to [Displaying more rows](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/displaying-more-rows)

With page annotated as `<apex:page readonly="true">` you'll be able to go up to 10,000 records.